# Not able to get request headers for flask python API on PythonAnywhere

Tags: python, flask, python-requests, http-headers, pythonanywhere

I have deployed a flask based python app on `PythonAnywhere`. It contains an API which need below request headers:

`app_name: <app-name>`

`app_key: <app-key>`

Below is the code:

```
@app.route('/api/app/get_id', methods=['POST'])
def get_id():
    try:
        if 'app_name' and 'app_key' in request.headers:
            """
            SOME CODE
            """
        else:
            return jsonify({"status": "unauthorized", "error": "authentication parameters missing"}), 401
    except Exception as e:
        log.error("Exception occurred {}".format(e))
```

As you can see that it needs `app_name` and `app_key`. If not found in headers, then API simply returns error. I am calling this API from postman and have included `app_name` and `app_key` :

[image]

But it always throws `error authentication parameters missing`. In my local testing it was working fine. I also tried debugging by putting logging like below:

```
@app.route('/api/app/get_id', methods=['POST'])
def get_id():
    try:
        log.error(request.headers)   # <-- logging
        if 'app_name' and 'app_key' in request.headers:
            """
            SOME CODE
            """
        else:
            return jsonify({"status": "unauthorized", "error": "authentication parameters missing"}), 401
    except Exception as e:
        log.error("Exception occurred {}".format(e))
```

But `app_name` and `app_key` were not there in log file as well. It looks like for some reason `PythonAnywhere` is not accepting these request headers. Does anyone know what is the issue and how can I resolve it. Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'app_name' and 'app_key'` evaluates to True in Python, so your if statement is asking if the key True is in the headers and it probably isn't.

Try using `if 'app_name' in request.headers and 'app_key' in request.headers'`